# Are level up bonuses applied cumulatively when multiclassing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, character-levels

I'm referring specifically to the fort ref and will save bonuses. say i'm a level 4 fighter, and thus have +4/+1/+1 respectively. i want to take a level in rogue for the +1d6 on sneak attacks, and looking at the rogue progression table, lv 1 is listed as 0/+2/0. so will i add 2 to my reflex saves or does it only increase TO 2? if i had a higher reflex save to begin with, would it revert upon multiclassing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're cumulative: they add together, not replace each other.

From the Pathfinder SRD section on [Multiclassing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Multiclassing):

> Instead of gaining the abilities granted by the next level in your character's current class, he can instead gain the 1st-level abilities of a new class, **adding all of those abilities to his existing ones**. This is known as “multiclassing.”
>
> For example, let's say a 5th-level fighter decides to dabble in the arcane arts, and adds one level of wizard when he advances to 6th level. Such a character would have the powers and abilities of both a 5th-level fighter and a 1st-level wizard, but would still be considered a 6th-level character. […] He **adds** all of the hit points, base attack bonuses, **and saving throw bonuses** from a 1st-level wizard **on top of those gained from being a 5th-level fighter**.

(Emphasis mine.)

So as a 4th-level Fighter levelling up and taking a level of Rogue, you'd be a Fighter 4/Rogue 1, a 5th-level character overall, and your saves would be +4/+3/+1.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the [fractional base bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes#TOC-Fractional-Base-Bonuses) variant, which dramatically improves the smoothness and consistency of BAB and saves for multiclassed characters.

Comment: I feel that answers are best when tailored to their intended audience.